# How can I get the address of the http management page of Juniper SSG-520?

Tags: firewall, juniper, juniper-network-connect

We have two Juniper.
One of them, we knows the ip address and can access the management page through the web UI.
However, the other one forgot the ip address and cannot access the management page.

Is it possible to find out the ip address of the management page through the console method?

I'm scared to touch the 0/3 Ethernet port because it's a device we're currently using. That's why I'm going to use the console port.